# SIgnin and signout need on different location in magento2

Tags: magento2

How to move signin and logout as per image in  magento2

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please tell us that links are a top link?

Comment: yes i have already moved authorization-link to top.links block


My question is how to display signin and signout with different place

Comment: I think you have to add the top links using your own block, for login link add the before the My order link, and write down the into block customer, not login than add the link otherwise not, as well as writedown block for the log out and if customer login than return the top links otherwise not, must be arranged the order with reference block and remove the authorization-link.

Answer (score 0):

if your link is top link then just follow the below step

1.please add below XML code int **default.xml** file

```
 <referenceBlock name="top.links">
                    <referenceBlock name="my-account-link">
                       <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </referenceBlock>
</referenceBlock>
```

2.Now just add sort order as per your requirement all the links

Thanks